# Нужно true, если только один, заранее определённый checkBox = true, иначе, false

Tags: c#

Задача состоит в создании приложения опросника, есть 4 checkBox, один из них "правильный" как сделать, чтобы при выборе нескольких элементов сразу было false, и только при выборе правильного, и одного, было  true

Comment: Проверить комбинацию выборов. "Если выбран второй и не выбран первый и не выбран третий и не выбран четвертый". Ну ,если бы правильным был второй :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы так сделал:

```
bool CheckResult(bool[] checks,int indexOfTrue)
{
    return checks[indexOfTrue] && checks.SingleOrDefault(x => x);
}
```

Снаружи пуляем значение чекбоксов в массив и передаем indexOfTrue- это номер корректного ответа.

Целиком `CheckBox` не передаем так как в этом нету смысла из-за того, что нам нужно всего 1 поле.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool Result(CheckBox checkBox1, CheckBox checkBox2, CheckBox checkBox3, CheckBox checkBox4)
    {
        //Вариант 1 выбраны все варианты ответов 
        if (checkBox1.Checked && checkBox2.Checked && checkBox3.Checked && checkBox4.Checked)
        {
            return false;
        }
        //вариант 2 тоько один вариант правельный это => checkBox2.Checked  если выбраны другие то ответ не верный
        if (checkBox1.Checked == false && checkBox2.Checked && checkBox3.Checked == false && checkBox4.Checked == false)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: В c# нет такого, что восклицательный знак означает отрицание? Т.е. не `if x==false`, а просто `if !x` ?

Comment: А просто `return x && y && z` в с# можно (без if, которое только загромождает код).

Comment: все это есть , тут вопрос читабельности кода

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего будет поместить эти чекбоксы в одну коллекцию, тогда с ними проще будет работать. Сделаем это в конструкторе. Если это `WinForms`, то код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private List<CheckBox> checkBoxes;
        private int rightAnswerIndex = 1; // Нумеруем с 0 

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            checkBoxes = new List<CheckBox>()
            {
                checkBox1,
                checkBox2,
                checkBox3,
                checkBox4
            };
        }

        public bool CheckIsTrue()
        {
            var checkedCount = 0;
            var checkedIndex = -1;
            for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.Count; i++)
            {
                if (checkBoxes[i].Checked)
                {
                    checkedCount++;
                    checkedIndex = i;
                }

                if (checkedCount == 2)
                    return false;
            }

            return checkedCount == 1 && checkedIndex == rightAnswerIndex;
        }
    }
}
```

Метод `CheckIsTrue` проверяет то условие, которое вам нужно. Его можно вызывать либо по нажатию кнопки, либо по изменению состояния чекбокса.

Answer (score 0):

Помещаешь комбобоксы в какой-нибудь элемент группировки:
Если `winforms` - то `Panel`; если `wpf` - `stackPanel` какой-нить или `Grid`.
И перебираешь их.

Для всех чекбоксов делаешь 1 обработчик нажатия

```
private void checkboxCheck(private object sender, EventArgs event) {
    var chekcboxs = panelWithCheckBox.Controls.TypeOf<CheckBox>();
    checkboxs.ForEach(control => { control.checked = false; });
    // У элементов есть свойство Tag которое можно заполнить строкой
    ((CheckBox)sender).checked = ((CheckBox)sender).Tag == "true" ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: Проголосовал в плюс т.к. решает задачу. Из проблем - даный код практически наверняка приведет к мельканию чекбокса.

Comment: нет. все так быстро происходит что ты не заметиш. 100 я так дела и не мелькает

Comment: подозреваю что это зависит от мощности компьютера) На одних, вероятно, будет норм, на других - будет мелькать :)